# How to get to know if I pass through a particular latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have a list of latitude and longitude together they are forming a polyline. Now I'm getting my current lats and long through gps.

So my question is how to detect if i pass through any of the latitude and longitude that is stored in the list.

Comment: Its already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546625/check-if-route-contains-a-specific-coordinates-or-not

Comment: @SSB thanks for your answer I will check it out

Comment: Good to know, welcome :)